# Chrome Extension Shortcuts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a simple extension that has a .js file with only 2 functions and a listener (which only writes to Console - but I can't see it and not sure it catches anything).

I'd like to have shortcuts assigned, let's say `Ctrl+Shift+1` and `Ctrl+Shift+2` to both functions.

I'm not exactly sure how to do it, and if it's possible. The data I've been able to gather online didn't cover what I'm looking for.

I have no need for html popup. All I want is to press the shortcut and have the correspondent javascript function execute.

This is how my manifest.json file looks like:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Simple Extension",
  "description": "This extension barely does anything.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html" //not sure I even need this
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["popup.js"]
  },

  "commands": {
      "funcA": {
        "suggested_key": {
          "default": "Ctrl+Shift+1"
        },
        "description": "Executes Func A"
      },
      "funcB": {
        "suggested_key": {
          "default": "Ctrl+Shift+2"
        },
        "description": "Executes Func B"
      }
   }
}
```

After installing the extension I saw on 'Keyboard Shortcuts' on the Extension tab that the shortcuts assignment worked well, but it's unclear to me what binds the shortcut to the javascript function itself.

Do I have to use a listener and then do the call manually ?

Edit:

This is the listener in my .js file:

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
        console.log('Command:', command);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Register an event listener for the [`chrome.commands.onCommand`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands#event-onCommand) event in the [background](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) or [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages).

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
    // Now, do whatever you want when the shortcut is triggered.
    // e.g. if (command == 'funcA') ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question with the `background` attribute you suggested, and how my listener on the javascript file looks like. However, I don't see in the console any listings when I use my shortcuts. Is it even possible to use custom commands? Or is there a restricted list?

Comment: Update: I added an "alert" line and I do get the alert. I'm assuming the `Console.log` does not update to the regular Chrome console then ?

Comment: You should look in the appropriate console. From `chrome://extensions` in Developer mode, you will see a link to the Dev Tools for your background page.

Comment: @OmriAharon Why did you call that file "popup.js"? To make sure that you understand the difference between background and popup page, read https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch. You can find the background console messages in the background page's console, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension

Comment: @RobW It's just a name from the tutorial, doesn't mean anything just yet.